# Graph-theory question regarding degrees and cliques

Tags: graph-theory

Suppose we have a graph $G$, where each node in there has a degree of at most $d$. I need to show that it is possible to determine if $G$ has a clique of size $k$ in time of at most $n^c \cdot d^k$ steps where $c$ is some constant.

Any help will be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each vertex $v$, denote by $\Gamma(v)$ the set of neighbors of $v$. For each vertex $v$, set $A_1:=\Gamma(v)$ and $C_1:=\{v\}$. In the following recursion, $A_i$ denotes the set of *possible* candidates to enter the clique and $C_i$ is the largest clique containing $v$ which we have already found:

For each $w\in A_i$, check whether $C_i\subseteq\Gamma(w)$. If so, then we have found a larger clique $C_{i+1}:=C_i\cup\{w\}$. Also, we can set $A_{i+1}:=\Gamma(w)\cap A_i$ since any vertex in an even larger clique will have to be a neighbor of all vertices in $C_{i+1}$. For performance reasons, we would stop as soon as $|A_i\cup C_i|<k$, of course.

If at some point you reach $i=k$, then $C_k$ is a clique of size $k$. On the other hand, if there is a clique of size $k$, then this procedure will find it by starting at any of its vertices. The running time is $nd^k$.

Comment: Great thanks :)